# What is the most efficient way to run several simulations of parameterized quantum circuits in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, simulation

Suppose I am given a parameterized quantum circuit in Qiskit: as an example, here I consider a [`ZZFeatureMap`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.ZZFeatureMap.html) ansatz, commonly used for data embedding in quantum machine learning appications:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZZFeatureMap

num_features = 3
pqc = ZZFeatureMap(num_features, reps=1).decompose()
pqc.measure_all()

pqc.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

What I want to do is to run `nsims` full simulations of the above circuit passing each time a different set of values to be assigned to the ansatz free parameters. Moreover, each single simulation has to be repeated a number of times equals to `shots` in order to get a statistically robust final outcome for the measurement operation.

The most straightforward way to do it in Qiskit should be something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import Aer

nsims = 1000
shots = 2048
parameter_values = np.random.rand(nsims, num_features)

simulator = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
for vals in parameter_values:
    job = simulator.run(pqc.assign_parameters(vals), shots=shots)
```

However, on my local CPU, this took more than 10 seconds already. I guess that here the problem is that every time I call the `assign_parameters` method inside the loop, Qiskit is actually creating a *deepcopy* of the whole circuit to make the parameter binding possible.

Another possibility I tried out is based on the [`Sampler`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.primitives.Sampler.html) primitive, provided by Qiskit itself:

```
from qiskit.primitives import Sampler

sampler = Sampler()
circuits = [pqc] * nsims 
job = sampler.run(circuits, parameter_values, shots=shots)
```

This solution is slightly better that the first one but still it looks pretty slow and far from being optimal. So, how can I make it faster? Is there an efficient way that maybe leverages more advanced Qiskit features?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running simulations of circuits with few qubits (like your example above), the `Sampler` should be the fastest out-of-the-box method to run the circuit. It's internally relying on the `Statevector` class, which just applies the gates and computes the full statevector -- this has almost no overhead so it's fast for small circuit, but starting from say 10+ qubits or really deep circuits this is likely going to be slower than Aer.

To marginally speed this approach up you could try using putting the `CX P(theta) CX` sequence in a two-qubit gate with a `to_matrix` method, so the `Statevector` can apply the full block at once instead of 3 individual gates.

If you want to avoid the deep copy, which you correctly identified as the bottleneck, you could use a hacky approach:

1. Create the circuit with *fixed* values of the first simulation
2. Evaluate the single circuit with the `Sampler`
3. Replace the gate angles of the `P` gate by iterating over `circuit.data`, finding the `PhaseGate`s and replacing `PhaseGate.params` with the new value
4. Go to 2 :)

This is a bit hacky as you have to manually compute the gate angles and iterate over the circuit data -- but it avoids the expensive copy. FYI, we're currently working on making circuits lightweight and copies cheap, so in the future this is hopefully not going to be a problem anymore.

I hope that helps!